# How gradle build a android project from source code to apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, apk

The following process shows to build  android project in eclipse before,but now android groups use gradle to build android project.

> ```
>  aapt -> R.java
>  aidl -> .java
>  javac -> class
>  dx.bat -> (.class->classes.dex)
>  aapt  -> resources.ap_
>  apkbuilder.bat -> {(resources + classes.dex) -> unsigned.apk }
>  jarsinger -> (unsigned.apk -> apksigned.apk)
> ```

I want to know how gradle build a android project like that.
In the process of the construction of gradle, is it still call the above command?
For example, does gradle use **jarsinger** to complete the process from unsigned.apk to apksigned.apk either? Or gradle has its process?

Comment: Just compile your build.gradle and gradle will build everything for you.

Comment: But I‘d like to know what gradle do .